# Why does adding 0 to the end of float literal change how it rounds (possible GCC bug)?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, floating-point

I discovered on my x86 VM (32 bit) that the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo (long double x) {
    int y = x;
    printf("(int)%Lf = %d\n", x, y);
}
int main () {
    foo(.9999999999999999999728949456878623891498136799780L);
    foo(.999999999999999999972894945687862389149813679978L);
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
(int)1.000000 = 1
(int)1.000000 = 0
```

[Ideone also produces this behavior.](http://ideone.com/tOJmNb)

What is the compiler doing to allow this to happen?

I found this constant as I was tracking down why the following program didn't produce `0` as I expected (using 19 `9`s produced the `0` I expected):

```
int main () {
    long double x = .99999999999999999999L; /* 20 9's */
    int y = x;
    printf("%d\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

As I tried to compute the value at which the result switches from expected to unexpected, I arrived at the constant this question is about.

Comment: Dupe hundreds of times over. [Read this.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: A classic dupe in fact.

Comment: Quick guess: That literal is larger than the largest number strictly `<1` representable in a double, so it being rounded to the closest `double` (i.e. `1.0`) before anything else happens.

Comment: Drop the `L` off the end of the first line and retry.

Comment: why not print out the bytes of the long double and see what the internal representation is before you convert it to int?

Comment: @trojanfoe: output is the same

Comment: @BoBTFish: Yes, I expected the value to be the largest number less than 1, not 1.

Comment: @hammar: I am not entirely familiar with all the rules of converting a floating point literal to a variable value, but in my head I round towards 0 like I do with integer math. That is, I expected any extra floating point bits beyond the precision to be truncated.

Comment: @user315052 [Look at this](https://ideone.com/98XUTH) and see that your literal falls closer to `1` than the next smallest representable `double`. Therefore it rounds to `1`. Just like (ignoring computers completely here) rounding `1.6` to an integer rounds up to `2`, rather than truncating to `1`.

Comment: To simplify the question, you can ask if 0.9 is closer to 1 or to 1/2, then closer to 1 or 3/4, and so forth.

Comment: @H2CO3 I have read this document and I do not see where the question is answered.

Comment: @user315052: A floating point literal can either be rounded to the nearest representable value, or to the next larger or smaller representable value.  It's implementation-defined which, so your implementation should document what it does.

Comment: @BoBTFish: Please see my edit. It doesn't really match with your sample program.

Comment: @caf: All that is well and good, but I didn't find a question on SO that answered the question in that way. Is it really appropriate to downvote this question just because I didn't know this was implementation defined behavior?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: No, floating point constants are converted *"as if at translation time"* which means that the execution-time rounding mode shouldn't affect it, and exceptions shouldn't be raised at execution time.

Comment: @user315052: I didn't downvote the question, and if it hadn't been closed, I'd have written that as an answer.

Comment: @caf: The question's been reopened.

Comment: @H2CO3: Thanks for the link to the document.

Comment: You know why you are able to edit questions? It is so that they can be *edited* and updated. You don't need to add edits at the bottom, and you don't need to highlight them with an **edit** heading. When editing a question, *edit* it. Update the question *as a whole*. When people read your question, show them one coherent and updated question rather than a bad question followed by a sequence of four edits, which the reader then has to try to combine in their heads.

Comment: @jalf: I guess I need to know what is bad about the original question. The other information is just supplementing questions asked and one to address reopening the question.

Comment: @user315052: well, if it wasn't bad, you wouldn't have needed to edit it, would you? ;) Every edit you make is because something about the original question should be improved. So make that improvement *to the question itself*, not in a separate section at the bottom. (and you really do not need to make an edit to inform the world that the question has been reopened. The purpose of the question is to be easily readable and understandable both for people who want to answer it, and for others having a similar problem and looking for an answer

Comment: @jalf: I have edited the question. Generally, I feel a question that generates positive discussion and adds knowledge should at worst be treated neutrally. I didn't expect such a negative reaction to what I feel was a unique question (to an admittedly well tread problem) that had a unique answer (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @user315052 Stack Overflow is not for discussion, it's for getting answers to questions. :-)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: One more edit puts this into community wiki territory. Why remove the `floating-point` tag? I still don't understand the reason this question is getting so many downvotes.

Comment: @user315052 I also removed the meta discussion from the question itself (the question shouldn't contain things like "Note to downvoters" or "Yes, this has been re-opened!").

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I don't have a problem with removing the meta discussion, but I am wondering why you thought the `floating-point` tag did not apply.

Comment: @H2CO3: I searched when I wrote the question, and I searched again now. I do not see why you claim this question is "Dupe hundreds of times over". I would really appreciate it if you can provide an example where this question is answered.

Comment: It's a "dupe" because it's caused by an extremely common problem - floating point values are hardly ever exact and need to be rounded to a value that can be represented in binary. The only unique thing about this question is the long double literal but that doesn't change the answer. If you want to find dupes just search for the link that @H2CO3 gave, it's probably in every one of them.

Comment: @user315052 If you had made the effort looking at the history of your own question, you would have perceived that it has been closed as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798338/floating-point-rounding-in-c) (which it indeed is).

Comment: @H2CO3: I don't even how those questions apply. Particularly with respect to the last part of the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I am not claiming I am opening a new frontier or anything. If you are talking about common problems, I don't see questions posted because of memory corruption getting downvoted because of that. As for the `long double` literal, I think the part of leaving the `0` on or off changing the rounding behavior is an interesting aspect of the question.

Comment: @H2CO3: I wish people would stop linking to that, it is literally the worst introduction to floating-point numbers I have ever seen.

Comment: @H2CO3: No, it's really not a duplicate of anything you've claimed it's a duplicate of.  A trailing zero should not have this effect.

Comment: haha I learned to never use floats/doubles/singles for real money applications like poker unless it's fake game money :)

Comment: I don't actually see any good answer to that question about the trailing 0. FYI, Visual Studio cpp compiler displays two 1 as expected. It looks like an enormous bug to me.

Comment: @SimonMourier: caf does say it is a bug at the end of his answer, and the question modified a bit from its original one. I authored this question when I didn't quite understand that improving a question by changing what is being asked wasn't really acceptable. In any case, caf took the original question seriously instead of dismissing it, and got me to understand rounding behavior is implementation defined.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your problem is that `long double` on your platform has insufficient precision to store the exact value 0.99999999999999999999.  This means that the value of that must be converted to a representable value (this conversion happens during translation of your program, not at runtime).

This conversion can generate either the nearest representable value, or the next greater or smaller representable value.  The choice is implementation-defined, so your implementation should document which it is using.  It seems that your implementation uses x87-style 80bit `long double`, and is rounding to the nearest value, resulting in a value of 1.0 stored in `x`.

---

With the assumed format for `long double` (with 64 mantissa bits), the highest representable number less than 1.0 is, in hexadecimal:

```
0x0.ffffffffffffffff
```

The number exactly halfway between this value and the next higher representable number (1.0) is:

```
0x0.ffffffffffffffff8
```

Your very long constant 0.9999999999999999999728949456878623891498136799780 is equal to:

```
0x0.ffffffffffffffff7fffffffffffffffffffffffa1eb2f0b64cf31c113a8ec...
```

which should obviously be rounded down if rounding to nearest, but you appear to have reached some limit of the floating point representation your compiler is using, or a rounding bug.

Comment: why would the trailing `0` make a difference?

Comment: Actually, the "next greater or smaller" rounding is only allowed by the standard if `FLT_RADIX` is NOT `2`.  If `FLT_RADIX` IS `2`, then it must be rounded correctly (to nearest).  Since `FLT_RADIX` is 2 for pretty much all machines these days (any that use IEEE binary fp), the trailing `0` issue would indicate a bug in the compiler (or at least a failure to conform to the standard).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, it's possible that the literal conversion assumes the trailing digit is a `5` rather than a `0` for rounding purposes.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: It's only hexadecimal floating constants that must be rounded correctly when `FLT_RADIX` is 2, the constants in the question are all decimal (at least, that is the case in C99).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I wrote this answer before that longer constant had been added to the question.  It does appear to be some kind of implementation bug.

Comment: This is correct but I'd like to point out a little more clearly that it's not a rounding error at runtime. It's that `.9999999999999999999L` is a numeric literal that represents (at least to this compiler version) the same number as the literal `1.0`. Nothing you do to it at any point is going to distinguish it from unity.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Then that would be an extremely bad compiler bug.

Answer (score 5):

Compiler uses binary numbers. Most compilers do the same thing.

According to wolframalpha, binary representation of

`0.99999999999999999999`

looks like this:

```
0.11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101000011000110101111011110011011011011011110111011100101000101010111011100001011010001001110001101011001010000110000101001111011111001111110000101010111111110100110000010001001101011001101010110110010010101101111101001110001100111101100000000100110110001100110000011000100100011000011110100001000000100001000101000111011010111111101011010010000010110011111110100100110001011001110100011100001111101011110101001000000111110010000101101001001010110010011001110111111100111101111100000111010001101101011000100110001010010001000100010110000101110100101010101001010100010001001100111111111001001101100000000010010001011110100101011101001001101001111001001000101011101001100111101110111111001101110100111000001111101101101101101110100100111101000000000111101101101001000111101100010101110011101110001110010110110111101000011110110100011000110101100011111111110111000010010001111000000000101100101000100101110100001001101000010110101000100011100000110010001110101...
```

That's 932 bits, and that STILL isn't enough to precisely represent your number (see dots at the end).

Which means that as long as your underlying platform uses base of 2 to store numbers, you will not be able to store exactly `0.99999999999999999999`.

Because number cannot be stored precisely, it'll be rounded up or down. With 20 9s it ends up being rounded up, and with 19 9s it ends up being rounded down.

To avoid this problem, instead of doubles you'll need to use some kind of 3rd party mathematics/bignum library that stores numbers internally using decimal base (i.e. two decimal digits per byte or something) or uses fractions (ratios) instead of floating point numbers. That would solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Double values, when there is not enough precision to represent a value, rounds up or down to the closest one.  In your implementation it is rounding up to 1.

Answer (score 2):

There are two conversions involved here. First, and in some ways most important, is the conversion of the literal `.99999999999999999999L` to long double. As others have said, this conversion rounds to the nearest representable value, which seems to be `1.0L`. The second conversion is from the long double value that resulted from the first conversion to an integer value. That conversion rounds toward 0, which is why a quick examination suggests that the value of `y` should be 0. But because the **first** conversion produced 1 and not a value slightly less than 1, this conversion also produces 1.