# Python String Conversion Based Upon Significant Digits

Tags: python

I'm looking for a string conversion function/module in Python that is based upon significant digits (figures).  The usefulness for this functionality has come up several times, so it seems hard to believe that Python *still* doesn't have a function or module to do this easily.  Does anyone know if anything new has come out?  If not, would this be a good opportunity for a feature request?

Disclaimers:

1. I realize that this is a topic that has several questions already, but most of them are several years old.  I'm hoping something has been released recently, as useful as it seems.
2. I also realize that it is relatively simple to write a function to do this manually, but I would prefer a module or (better) a built-in function for portability.
3. I'm not looking for the output to be in exponential notation

Functionality examples:

```
>>> from somemodule import SDStr

>>> SDStr(num=1234, sigDigs=3)
'1230'

>>> SDStr(num=12.3456, sigDigs=4)
'12.35'

>>> SDStr(num=100, sigDigs=3)
'100.'

>>> SDStr(num=100.0, sigDigs=2)
'100'

>>> SDStr(num=100, sigDigs=4)
'100.0'

>>> SDStr(num=0.001234, sigDigs=2)
'0.0012'
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18886013/5987 for the start of an answer. There's code to round to a fixed 15 decimal places but it could be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import decimal

def rounded(number, figures):
    number = decimal.Decimal(number)
    return format(round(number, -number.adjusted()-1+figures), "f")
```

`decimal` keeps track of decimal digits, so obviously this is the way to do things.

I just adjust the number of significant figures by the place of the most significant digit and format it to a float. It works like a charm.

**EDIT:** For some reason Python 2's not liking this. I'll look into it.

Well, basically in Python 2 `round` coerces to a `float` (seriously, move to Python 3), so the simple answer is:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def rounded(number, figures):
    number = Decimal(number)
    decimal_shift = -number.adjusted()-1+figures
    integral = round(number * Decimal(10) ** decimal_shift)
    rounded_decimal = Decimal(integral) * Decimal(10) ** -decimal_shift
    return format(rounded_decimal, "f")
```