# Python:computing the number of digits after decimal gives wrong answer

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, decimal, odoo-8

I have a floating point field in one of my form, consider it as *field_x*. Based on that *field_x* i have some computation.
**After all if *field_x* have n digits after decimal result also should have n digits.**

For example:
field_x = 0.00000001(n digits after decimal)

result = some calculations

if result = 22
i have to display it as 22.00000000(n digits after decimal)

`len(str(number-int(number))[1:])` Gives the answer

**here the number can be 0.00101,0.110,0.787,etc

But for some values like *0.000001* its giving incorrect answer

Comment: for your example the string is `1e-06` !! wrong method.

Comment: ys i know..thats why is asked for an answer

Comment: floats have an internal representation that may surprise you. So when entering 0.00001 to a `decimal.Decimal` object I get `0.000010000000000000000818030539140313095458623138256371021270751953125` ... difficult to answer the question. If the number is entered/read from a file, then use the string representation to compute your value, don't cast to float.

Comment: yup.........i tried....if its decimal.Decimal(<string>) its ok

Comment: can you help converting .00000001 to string exactly like this

Comment: sorry, that's not possible if you enter the data in a float due to loss of precision when converting your string to a float. Can you widen your problem. Where do the numbers come from?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes it is possible to find the minimal decimal fraction back even after converting to float http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886012/convert-float-to-rounded-decimal-equivalent/18905753#18905753

Comment: @PsP: What if the user enters "1.00200" in the form? How many digits after the decimal should that count as? If you need to count that as 5 digits after the decimal, then you'll need to get hold of the actual string entered into the form *before* it's converted to a `float` (or configure the form so that you receive a `Decimal` object rather than a `float`). Once you have a `float`, that information is not recoverable.

Answer (score 0):

I have'nt found a proper answer for this issue anywhere.
Either we need to use double precision which it is not possible in odoo or we have to convert to string and get the exponential length.
I have chosen second one.
Thank you