# C++ Precision behavior with double/long double

Tags: c++, type-conversion, precision

I am just curious about something.

I have the following code:

```
if (d1 == 2.3)
    cout << "2.3 is my value\n";
if (d1 == 2.2999999999999998)
    cout << "2.2999999999999998 is my value\n";
```

VS2013 c++11 screenshots

[image]

[image]

And it goes into both ifs. I know the precision for double is with 15decimals, so I will have to use a more appropiated type for this kind of data.

Could anybody link me a detailed reference? And also a "way" to storage just "2.3" or a data with more precision than 2.2999999999999998? (long double throws me complie error

```
Error   1   error C2398: Element '1': conversion from 'long double' to 'const 
std::complex<double>::_Ty &' requires a narrowing conversion...
```

Thanks.

Edit: Added complex

[image]

Comment: Try reading over [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16831464/315052). Also, did you try `complex<long double>`?

Comment: Yes, I tried with complex<long double> and there is no compile error, but they both storage still 2.99999999999998

Comment: "I know the precision for double is with 15decimals" - Uhm, well... [It's a bit more complicated than that.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the nature of floating point - there is no way to represent 2.3 exactly as a floating point binary.

The "2.3" in your first test can't be represented exactly in binary, so it's stored as the closest possible `double`, which is `2.2999999999999998`.
In other words, both `if`s perform the same comparison.

Comment: I know about the binary problem, so I was just thinking on how about some "string" storage conversion, or a bigger precision type, but long double throws me the error I posted.

Comment: @blacai You'd need an infinite amount of storage in order to be able to represent all numbers exactly. You're always going to run into a limit somewhere. You can decide on what precision you're after, then implement that yourself, but it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe reading this might help you:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/34088/

As far as i can tell there seems to be no real reference except with the compiler you use. Try http://msdn.microsoft.com
I suppose 2.2999999999999998 is beeing rounded to the closest double value which would be 2.3, or the other way around as the other answerer suggests. if you want long double literals, you need to add a L at the end of your literal:

```
//checks for equalty to a double
if (d1 == 2.2999999999999998)
    cout << d1 << " == 2.2999999999999998 ?\n";
//checks for equalty to a long double
if (d1 == 2.2999999999999998L)
    cout << d1 << " == 2.2999999999999998L ?\n";
```

btw: why dont you use

```
complex<long double>
```

?

Comment: Cplusplus forums and tutorials, please dont. Cplusplus is a source of errors, outdated practices, and missunderstandings

Comment: As I answered before, I also try with complex<long double> but it seems the same to me with '2.999999999999998'

Comment: '2.999999999999998' is not the same as '2.999999999999998L'