# double numbers precision in C

Tags: c, floating-point

why does

```
printf("is 0.5 <= 0.49999999999999999 ? %s", 0.5 <= 0.49999999999999999 ? "true":"false" );
```

return

```
is 0.5 <= 0.49999999999999999 ? true
```

*it's not a homework, just curious.

Comment: Because `0.49999999999999999` cannot be represented in `double`.

Comment: Well, it should be a homework question. At least, it was, when I was in school.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16831464/315052).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to answer your question is by changing the line of code slightly:

```
printf("is %.16e <= %.16e ? %s", 0.5, 0.49999999999999999, 0.5 <= 0.49999999999999999 ? "true":"false" );
```

Compiling this line, you will see that `0.49999999999999999` is rounded to the nearest representable `double`, which is the same as for `0.5` (and indeed represents the exact value 1/2). This explains why one is lower than or equal to the other: they are two different notations for the same thing.

---

Note: I chose the format `%.16e` as this format has the property never to print the same thing for distinct double-precision floating-point numbers. Experts prefer to use the hexadecimal format `%a`. Not only hexadecimal is more compact, but using it makes immediately obvious that `0.5` is represented exactly (it is `0x0.8p0` or `0x1.0p-1`) and some other decimal numbers, such as 0.1, aren't (in hexadecimal the digits repeat and use up all the significand). In short, using hexadecimal for inputing and printing floating-point numbers will instantly make you a pro.